# NUnit create a test with a ModelViewFactory and a repository Mock

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I'm having some troubles to create a NUnit test with a `ModelViewFactory` and a repository mock.

My test should test if my controller Get-function returns a list of `InternshipsViewModel`s.

My controller:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetInternshipsForCoordinator()
{
    return Ok(new InternshipsViewModelFactory().CreateInternshipsViewModel(_internshipRepository, _internshipRepository.GetAll()));
}
```

And my test:

```
public void Get_ShouldReturnListOfInternshipsViewModel()
{
    //Arrange
    var allInternshipWithFeedbackViewModels = new List<InternshipsWithFeedbackViewModel>
    {
        new InternshipWithFeedbackViewModelBuilder().Build()
    };

    Mock<InternshipsViewModelFactory> internshipViewModelFactoryMock = new Mock<InternshipsViewModelFactory>();
    internshipViewModelFactoryMock.Setup(
        c =>
            c.CreateInternshipsViewModel(It.IsAny<IInternshipRepository>(),
                It.IsAny<IEnumerable<Internship>>())).Returns(() => allInternshipWithFeedbackViewModels);

    //Act
    var okResult =
        _controller.GetInternshipsForCoordinator() as
            OkNegotiatedContentResult<IEnumerable<InternshipsWithFeedbackViewModel>>;

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(okResult);

}
```

I know that I should use more Asserts, and I will use more when this one works.
The error I get is [image: Error message]

Can someone please help me? Help is much appreciated because I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the method under test is directly newing up the factory. The means that is unable to be replaced with a mock for the test.

Consider abstracting the factory behind and interface to allow for more flexibility when replacing it in tests.

```
public interface IInternshipsViewModelFactory {
    IEnumerable<InternshipsWithFeedbackViewModel> CreateInternshipsViewModel(IInternshipRepository internshipRepository, IEnumerable<Internship> internships);
}
```

Make sure the implementation inherits from the above interface/abstraction.

Invert the control in the controller by having that dependency injected into the controller.

For example

```
public class MyController : ApiController {
    IInternshipsViewModelFactory factory;
    IInternshipRepository _internshipRepository;

    public MyController(IInternshipsViewModelFactory factory, IInternshipRepository repository) {
        this.factory = factory;
        this._internshipRepository = repository;
    }

    public IHttpActionResult GetInternshipsForCoordinator() {
        var models = factory.CreateInternshipsViewModel(_internshipRepository, _internshipRepository.GetAll());
        return Ok(models);
    }
}
```

This would allow you to mock the factory, inject it into the controller under test and mock the desired behavior for the test.

```
public void Get_ShouldReturnListOfInternshipsViewModel() {
    //Arrange
    var allInternshipWithFeedbackViewModels = new List<InternshipsWithFeedbackViewModel> {
        //...populate collection
    };

    var internshipViewModelFactoryMock = new Mock<IInternshipsViewModelFactory>();
    internshipViewModelFactoryMock
        .Setup(_ => _.CreateInternshipsViewModel(It.IsAny<IInternshipRepository>(), It.IsAny<IEnumerable<Internship>>()))
        .Returns(() => allInternshipWithFeedbackViewModels);

    var repositoryMock = new Mock<IInternshipRepository>();
    repositoryMock.Setup(_ => _.GetAll()).Returns(new List<Internship>());

    var _controller = new MyController(internshipViewModelFactoryMock.Object, repositoryMock.Object);

    //Act
    var okResult =
        _controller.GetInternshipsForCoordinator() as
            OkNegotiatedContentResult<IEnumerable<InternshipsWithFeedbackViewModel>>;

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(okResult);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you cannot mock `InternshipsViewModelFactory` as it's a concrete, non-abstract type. You should create (and use) an interface `IInternshipsViewModelFactory` instead.

Then Mock will be able to create its own implementation of `IInternshipsViewModelFactory` which will act the way you describe in your mock's Setup method.